# Python ValueError: invalid literal for int(): '1.5'

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to calculate the sum of an integer sequence divided by comma.

My code is:

```
s = raw_input('Input sequence of integers divided by commas: ')
i = 0
pointer = 0
sLen = len(s)
seqSum = 0.00

for i in range(0,sLen):
    if s[i] == ',':
        print s[pointer:i]
        seqSum = seqSum + int(s[pointer:i])
        pointer = i+1

seqSum = seqSum + int(s[pointer:sLen])
print str(seqSum)
```

For example, `1.5,1.5,1.5`

But I'm getting: `ValueError: invalid literal for int(): '1.5'` - how do I fix this?

Comment: `1.5` is not an integer, now, is it.

Comment: Also, you can simplify your code a lot: `print sum(float(x) for x in s.split(','))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have floating point values, not integers. Use `float()` instead if you want to support such numbers.

Comment: Thank you, was pretty obvious